# Cardconnect Cardpointe Woocommerce Partial Void

Tags: woocommerce

we are using cardconenct plugin as payment option in woocommerce.
However we can not do a partial void if the payment is set to capture payment.

I'm thinking of changing it to authorize only, so we can do a partial refund.
Howver for some reason, the capture api endpoint is not working.

it is not returning any data.

```
`public function captureTransaction($request) {
            // do security
            if ($this->rateLimit($request)) {
                return 'hammered';
            }
            if ($this->hammeredCard($request)) {
                return 'banned';
            }
            if ($this->hammeredOrder($request)) {
                return 'order_ban';
            }
            return self::send($this->ENDPOINT_CAPTURE, $this->OP_PUT, $request);
        }

 $response_capture = $test->get_cc_client()->captureTransaction($request);`
```

I'm really stuck. hope anyone can help

Comment: What do you mean "it's not returning any data"? No http status code? No body? Nothing at all? No errors either?

Comment: I keep getting HTTP 500

Comment: An error 500 means there's a server internal error (meaning, it's not your fault, but something that was wrong at the server backend)... I'm not saying it's not your fault (can't say with the provided code), because it's not an exact science and bugs happen, but it **should** mean that